# Rerouting=> http://localhost:3000/today_attendance?date=2019-03-29 TO http://localhost:3000/today_attendance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, export, xls

```
**Controller**
  def today_attendance
    @date = params[:date]?Date.parse(params[:date]): Date.today
    @attendances = Attendance.joins(:user).where(date: @date).select(:email, 
    :password, :date, :status)
  end

**Views** (Just changed from GET to POST method)
   <%= button_to '<', attendance_path(date: @date - 1.day) %>
   <%= "#{@date.strftime("%A")}, #{@date.strftime("%d")} #{@date.strftime("%B")} #{@date.year}" %>
   <%= button_to '>', attendance_path(date: @date + 1.day) %>

**Routes**
  resources :users do
  resources :attendances
  end
  get 'today_attendance', to: 'attendances#today_attendance', as: 'today_attendance'
  resource :calendar, only: [:today_attendance], controller: :attendances
  post 'today_attendance', to: 'attendances#today_attendance', as: 'attendance'
```

Hi am new @ Rails here.

Currently I have a daily attendances table that is linked to date. On my page shows 'Next Day' and 'Previous Day' buttons that brings my attendances from today to other days.

My current URL shown is: http://localhost:3000/today_attendance
And whenever I do click on the buttons, it gets me for e.g. http://localhost:3000/today_attendance?date=2019-03-29

**Question:** How do I redirect this page back to http://localhost:3000/today_attendance so that my export to .xls can read/to print out different day attendances?

Comment: So you want to keep the same url (http://localhost:3000/today_attendance) no matter if the user clicked on the `Next Day` or `Previous Day`?

Comment: Yes that is my intention.

Comment: Then you should not use the `GET` request but rather `POST` or do ajax requests.

Comment: Would it be possible to use POST as a redirect instead of updating a model? I do not wish to update any parameters as I view 'Next Day' & 'Previous Day' attendances.

Comment: Of course, everything is possible. The question is - what's wrong with the query params (http://localhost:3000/today_attendance?date=2019-03-29). It should not break your code. Also, it tells you exactly what you can expect when visiting this page. If you will use POST request, it will not be possible to share the link to attendances for a particular date (you have to submit form).

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly add a code snippet of your routes in your `routes.rb`,  and of your html for the button?

From my first assumption I believe your button may be doing a `GET` instead of a `POST` (from the addition of the `?date=2019-03-29` query in the uri).

Another issue may be your button isn't specified to be a `POST` method. It could be that either you forgot to specify `<button type="submit" >`. So code snippets may help to further narrow down the issue :)

Comment: **Uploaded my code snippet, now working through the POST method to get a redirect to /today_attendance instead

Comment: well if all you want to do is redirect after the post.. then just add a redirect back to `/today_attendance` in the controller. You can add a  `redirect_to today_attendance_path` at the end of `#today_attendance` .. 
Just so I'm understanding correctly, you want to call the action...  query for attendees with the date given.. and then redirect BACK to the that page to receive another date?

Comment: or as MrShemek said, you can look to do an AJAX request.. with a .js.erb file and rerender the page that way

Comment: I would like /today_attendace to stay as it is whichever date i query to. Say for e.g. I click on next day to get next day's attendees, the page will remain on that day(just that the URL would remain as /today_attendance instead of /today_attendance?date=2019-03-29.

Comment: so with adding `redirect_to today_attendance_path` you lose your query correct? .. so either you pass in the query as params to the redirect `redirect_to today_attendance_path(params[:date])` which seems like a roundabout way.. or Ajax might be a more elegant solution and save you a page reload.

Comment: I will give Ajax a try. Thank you Bryan :) (and credits to MrShemek)

Comment: Just a heads up, AJAX is a little unique with Rails
1. Make sure add `remote: true` onto your button
2. run a `respond_to` block in your controller which will format to js and html (`format.js, format.html`)
3. add a `js.erb` file so for yours it would be similar to `today_attendance.js.erb` and that's where you'll handle the AJAX through javascript magic

Comment: Thank you for the awesome heads up Bryan!! Your help has been most prompt and informative! Good day to you my friend :)